# After showing output using jQuery ajax the value doesn't pass using PHP post method

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I try to sum two data using AJAX and display it into hidden text input after that, I will pass the variable using PHP post method.

There are no problems in my jQuery AJAX code but the problem is after I submit the button, the value I retrieve from textbox `total_rec[]` is blank.

Here's my code below.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>user/recitem_insert"> 
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Test</th></tr></thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr><td>
<input type="hidden" name="last_item_rec[]" value="<?php echo $row->rec_qty; ?>">
<input type="text" name="item_rec[]" id="txt" disabled="">
<input type="hidden" name="total_rec[]" value="">
</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>   
</form>
```

JQUERY AJAX:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=item_rec\\[\\]]").on('keyup',function(){
        var one = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name=last_item_rec\\[\\]]').val();
        var two = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name=item_rec\\[\\]]').val();       

        sum =  parseInt(one) + parseInt(two);

        $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name=total_rec\\[\\]]').val(sum);        
    });
});
<script>
```

PHP CODE: (`recitem_insert.php`)

```
$total_rec = $_POST['total_rec'];

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){   
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($total_rec);$j++){
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tblstock 
                             SET             
                             rec_qty='$total_rec[$j]'
                             WHERE id = '$check[$i]'
                             ")or die(mysqli_error($con));  
    }               
}
```

Comment: FYI `$('input[name="item_rec[]"]')` is much easier to read 

Comment: Can you share your complete form? Where is your button? and what does it do? Only submit the form normal way or using ajax?

Comment: @muasif80 Hi sir, I've just submit it in normal way using post method <form action="PHP FILE" method="POST">

Comment: Before submitting the form using button have you checked in view source if the value is indeed present in the hidden field?

Comment: @muasif80 yes, first I change the type into text then after I confirm that there is a value showing I change the type into hidden.

Comment: Please check that you have the `method="post"` set in the form tag like this `<form method="post" ...`

Comment: @muasif80 yes sir it has..

Comment: I know now the problem. When I try to echo the result it is displayed but when i try to put in the query it doesn't show. How come that is was happen.. T_T

Comment: Where is the code that POSTs?  If it is JS, show us the code; if it is just a normal form, show us the code.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please see it now.

Comment: Your JS is looking for table rows (`tr`), but there are no `tr`s in the code you've shown us ... What is `$check`? What does `print_r($_POST)` look like?  Also, [you should really pass a 2nd parameter to `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description)  (10, I guess).

Comment: @Don'tPanic i've already edit the code, you can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

As you told that the item contain 2 or more value. So you can use class instead of name.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" class="last_item_rec" name="last_item_rec[]"  value="23" />
<input type="text" class="item_rec" name="item_rec[]"  id="txt" />
<input type="hidden" class="total_rec" name="total_rec[]" value="" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
$(".item_rec").on('keyup',function(){
  var one = $(this).parents('tr').find('.last_item_rec').val();
  var two = $(this).parents('tr').find('.item_rec').val(); 
  sum =  parseInt(one) + parseInt(two);
  console.log(sum);

  $(this).parents('tr').find('.total_rec').val(sum);        
});
});
```